# How to assign array value into variable inside foreach loop in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have an array of users with different userIds and I am trying to loop these array using a foreach loop. Inside that loop I am calling a function to get values of each users by passing their userid into a function. But its only passing one index of array.

My code

```
public function getDailyReportTest($orgId, $date)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT *  FROM `organization_users` WHERE orgId='7'");

       $timestamp = strtotime($date);
       $day = date('l', $timestamp);


   $data = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {

  $data[$i]['date']    = $date;
  $data[$i]['day']     = $day;
  $data[$i]['user_id'] = $row['orgUserId'];
  $data[$i]['user_name'] = $row['orgUserName'];


  $data[$i]['workingHours'] = self::getUserWorkingHours($data[$i]['user_id'],$date);

  $delayTime=self::getUserDelayTime($row['orgUserId'],$date);
  $shortTime=self::getUserShortTime($row['orgUserId'],$date);
  $overTime=self::getUserOverTime($row['orgUserId'],$date);

     $data[$i]['delayTime']   =$delayTime;
     $data[$i]['shortTime']   =$shortTime;
     $data[$i]['overTime']    =$overTime;

   $data[$i]['shift1_start'] = self::getUserShiftStartTime($row['orgUserId'], $date);  


  $i=$i+1;
}
//return $data;
print_r($data);
die();

}

public function getUserShiftStartTime($userId, $date)
{
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `office_employee_assigned_shifts` WHERE employeeId='$userId' &&shiftdate='$date'");
    $entry = $query->num_rows();

    $data = $query->result_array();

    if($entry==0)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        $shiftId = $data[0]['shiftId'];
        $shiftquery = $this->db->query("SELECT startTimeSpan, endTimeSpan FROM `office_shift_time` WHERE officeShiftId='$shiftId'");
        $dataShift = $shiftquery->result_array();
        $startSpan = $dataShift[0]['startTimeSpan'];
        $endSpan = $dataShift[0]['endTimeSpan'];


        $firstPunchQuery = $this->db->query("SELECT punchTime AS firstPunch FROM `employee_punch_log` WHERE punchDate='$date' && employeeId='140' && punchTime BETWEEN '$startSpan' AND '$endSpan' AND punchType='1' LIMIT 1");
        $punchEntryCount  = $firstPunchQuery->num_rows();
         if($punchEntryCount>0)
         {
        $dataFirstPunch = $firstPunchQuery->result_array();
        $firstPunchStartTime = $dataFirstPunch[0]['firstPunch'];
        return $firstPunchStartTime;
         }
         else
         {
             return "AB";
         }


    }
   // return $entry;
}
```

It only passes the $data[1]['user_id'].

I want to pass $data[0]['user_id'], $data[1]['user_id'], $data[2]['user_id'] to the function
named getUserShiftStartTime($userId, $date)

Any Help?
Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: There is no call to function getUserShiftStartTime() in your code. and when you print $data, how many records are there in this array?

Comment: @TufailAhmad miss it: Updated

Comment: Is there only one record in your array when you print $data?

Comment: This code looks too complex for what it does. Code should have the minimum complexity for what is solves, and in this case that cannot be verified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then pass the current variable to your method:

```
self::getUserShiftStartTime($data[$i]['user_id'], $date);
```